# Multiple ajax request/Multi threading

Tags: .net, ajax, multithreading

I've got a page where user clicks a button to install a sql database on the machine. The Install method is called when button is clicked:

```
        //mvc conroller
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Install(InstallModel model)
        {
            //expensive operation
        }

        //index.cshtml 
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Install", "Install", new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnBegin = "onStart",
        }))

        onStart: function (context) {
                window.setInterval(checkProgress, 1500);
            }

        function checkProgress() {
                  $.ajax({...
```

The onStart function sends an async ajax request every 1.5 seconds to check progress of the installation.
Can my page still send ajax requests while the Install method is still being run? How will the request be handled by .net? New thread for each request? If new Worker thread is created for each ajax request, Whats the benefit of running Install async? 
Btw the state of the installation is stored in memory cache. The ajax request basically calls a method that looks at the cache to find out whats going on with the installation and sends a response back to the page in json.